# Minecraft: java.net.connectexception no further information. Me and my girlfriend get this error when we try joining each other's lan worlds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, hamachi

As stated in the title, we get the error `Minecraft: java.net.connectexception` whenever we try to connect to each other's LAN worlds. We have tried several fixes including:

- Using Hamachi
- Turning off our firewalls
- Creating new inbound rules for Minecraft
- Installing a different version of Minecraft

Nothing so far has worked. We can connect to other servers just fine, but can never join each other's LAN worlds.

Any suggestions or fixes, would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance you wonderful person <3.

Comment: By rule you mean port?

Comment: I know you mentioned that you messed with the firewall and firewall rules on your PC, but I would try [these steps](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/1868373-java-net-connectexception-connection-timed-out-no) posted by Void Walker in the order they listed.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i tried all of these steps previously, none of them yielded results.

Comment: Are you both on the same network? (ie. connected to the same router/switch)

Comment: @galacticninja Can you expand on how are they the same? This one seems to be having a problem with Java, whereas the suggested duplicate is a Minecraft server issue (it seems to my Minecraft-layman eyes).

Comment: @Joachim I searched the error message before voting to close and found these questions that seem to have also been asked about the same issue: [Minecraft LAN “java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information:”](/q/347979/4797), [java.net.connectexception: Connection refused: no further information via server](/q/351490/4797). Both were closed as a dupe of the above question I linked to. It seems to me that the error messages are about the same issue.

Comment: @galacticninja Thanks, yes, I noticed that too. Searching for "connection refused" results in a list of similar duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is probably a firewall problem. Have both of your computers have firewall disabled on both public and home networks? My sister and I tried this after going days without being able to play lan and it worked but if you do not wish to do this then here is a way to let programs through your firewall, not ports. And also realise that Minecraft now has built in Java so please post the executable path in the launcher's edit profile section. So to begin go to the start menu and paste this in:

```
Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Allowed Programs
```

Then click change settings:

[image: Allow Programs section]

Then press allow another program...:

And then what you must do is paste what is in your executable which you found in the Minecraft launcher:
[image: Executable Location]
.
And then click add. I hope this help's you

Comment: Thank you for the answer :), but i already tried doing that, it didn't have an effect and the problem persisted. I attempted doing it again, but it gave me a message saying that i already added that to the list of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

My brother and I had the same problem. I couldn't connect to his server and we used the exact same programs.

Here's the solution: swap roles, have whoever is hosting at the moment try letting the other person try hosting instead.

We tried this, so now I'm hosting. Now, my brother and I can finally play together.

Comment: And please put your firewall backup!!!