# How to play minecraft with a friend without using the internet

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to play Minecraft on my friend's world without using internet? We used to play using wifi, but because of some problem, the wifi is not available now.

Is there any way to play minecraft with him without using the internet?

Comment: Both get a cable and connect your computers directly to the modem. But solving your WIfi might be your first priority, If your ISP is resolving the problem with your wifi modem you can always directly connect another wifi router on your modem with a UTP/COAX cable and use that router for temporary wifi until you either get a new modem or someone fixes it.

Comment: I tried to access a friend's Minecraft Java Edition 1.14.4 single-player world using "Open to LAN" on a LAN that was not connected to the Internet, but we only got error messages that the "authentication server" could not be reached. This suggests that Internet connectivity to a Mojang authentication server is required to share a world.

Answer (score 2):

Given your question, I'm assuming you are so close that you are using a single Wi-Fi connection.

It's worth trying to use an Android phone with no internet and run Wi-Fi tethering on it. You'll be connected to the same Wi-Fi network you jost won't be connected to the internet.

Comment: Hmm do you mean this for the pocket edition or is this for the pc version? How would this work i've never heard of tethering like this.

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket Wi-Fi tethering is a function of most android phones that lets you share the phone's internet connection with other devices through wifi. It does this by effectively being a wifi router. OP means that you can turn this function on, without the phone having an internet connection, and it'll be like your two PCs are connected to the same wifi, without internet being available.

Comment: Wow, I will have to try this. Probably could've used it years ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's an easy thing to do and the only thing that I found would take a while to set up. I found it from [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140316201946AAeSJaj) thread.

> You could set up "ad-hoc" wireless between the computers (instead of normal infrastructure/AP mode), but you may need to manually configure IP address for each computer, with unique IP for each and same netmask that puts them all on the same network. Not sure if that would work for "Open to LAN" on Minecraft. But if someone has a 64-bit OS and enough RAM, they could run a separate Minecraft server and their client on the same computer.

Also from the same thread is a suggestion to use ethernet which 
may cost money but is most likely  the only thing going to work

> I don't know much about Bluetooth but you guys can try to play with 2 on each server assuming there's 4 of you by using Ethernet cables so if you have a PC select a partner and the one to be host has to open to lan the both computers has to be connected using the Ethernet cable just plug it in and that's all don't mess with the options etc. just go to Minecraft open to lan and then he can join from the multiplayer tab in Minecraft

All that I can tell you is that there is no easy way to do this. There's no Bluetooth mod out there for Minecraft as I would assume a quick google would find it easily.

Also for an answer I posted earlier which may fix the lan problem itself is found [here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/299497/minecraft-java-net-connectexception-no-further-information-me-and-my-girlfrien)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not if you are using Minecraft Java Edition: this web page lists the Mojang servers that you need to have Internet connectivity with:
https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1452251-minecraft-java-edition-services